# Hibernate Search (Lucene) return empty result in case of '=' in string

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I configured Lucene to search my Hibernate model by value in column `test`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
@Audited
@Indexed
public class Test {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TEST")
    @Field(index = Index.YES,analyze = Analyze.YES,store = Store.NO)
    private String test;

    ...
}
```

In database Test model contains following test column values:

1. AB=ABC
2. AB=BCD

I created following code for searching by column value:

```
String queryValue = "AB";
QueryBuilder qb = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em).getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Test.class).get();
Query query = qb.all().createQuery();

BooleanJunction<BooleanJunction> conjuction = qb.bool();
String searchValue = new StringBuilder().append("*").append(queryValue .toLowerCase()).append("*").toString();
conjuction.should(qb.keyword().wildcard().onFields(new String[] { "test"}).matching(searchValue).createQuery());
query = conjuction.createQuery();

FullTextQuery textQuery = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em).createFullTextQuery(query, Test.class);
return textQuery.getResultList();
```

Above code works find for value `AB` and Lucene return me 2 records, but when I am looking for `AB=` it returns me empty result.

---

UPDATE

Here's the code for indexing:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

Do you know why I am getting empty result, since Lucen should return me 2 records? How I can fix it?

Comment: how are you indexing it ?

Comment: I mean indexing it by ID

Comment: what is the analyzer you are using while indexing ?

Comment: I didn't register any custom analyzer, so probably its OOTB string analyzer

Comment: can you post the code which you used to create index ?

Comment: Please take a look on update section, I have put the code that I am using during start up of my application to run indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the Analyzer used is StandardAnalyzer 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#analyzer

The standaranalyzer splits tokens on `=`  and remove the `=` also from the resulting tokens.

so in your case when you index `AB=ABC`  , the following tokens are created.

> AB, ABC

That is why when you search for `*AB*` you get results

But when you search for `*AB=*` you do not find anything, since there is no such token.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. Do you know what is the best way to fix it and how to fix it?

Comment: If you do not want your token to be split on "=" you can use something like `keywordTokenizer`. This will take the whole sentence as on token. It all depends how do you want to search for your stored things. I would suggest that you read about analyzers in lucene.

Comment: Analyzers are extremely powerful, rather than "fix this" you should try to benefit from the advantages of picking the right ones for your goal. If you simply want an "exact match" (also called a TermQuery), use analyze=NO on the Field annotation.